# How do I save the value of the tableviewcell with a checmark and pass it to another view controller, programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkmark

I want to save the name of the expertise which has been checkmarked and pass the expertise name to another uitableviewcontroller cell.

The array of expertisetype has the list of expertise.

import UIKit

class OriginalController: UITableViewController {

```
var pickedExpertise: String?
var typeExpertise = ["Marketing", "Sales", "Tech", "Finance"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return typeExpertise.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = typeExpertise[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark


    }





}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {

        cell.accessoryType = .none

    }
}
```

//different view controller

import UIKit

class NewController: UITableViewController {

```
var pickedExpertise2: String = "Expertise"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Test 1"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

let cellID = "cellID"

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)



    switch indexPath.section {

    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text 1 "
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text 2 "

    case 3:

        cell2.textLabel?.text = "expertise"


        cell2.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        return cell2
    case 4:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text 4"

    default:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Text default "
    }


    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let headerLabel = UILabel()
    headerLabel.text = "Name"
    switch section {
    case 0:
       headerLabel.text = "Name 0"
    case 1:
        headerLabel.text = "Name 1"
    case 2:
        headerLabel.text = "Name 2"
    case 3:
        headerLabel.text = "Name 3"

    default:
        headerLabel.text = "Name 4"
    }

    return headerLabel
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 3 {

        let expertiseC = OriginalController()

        navigationController?.pushViewController(expertiseC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have the `indexPath` of the selected row, from `didSelectRowAt`, you can either use it to get the `row` value and store it directly, or use it to look up the item in the `typeExpertise`.  You can the use that information and call `performSegue` and pass through the value as the `sender` parameter ... assuming you're using storyboards and segues.  In `prepareForSegue` you would then determine the `destination` view controller and the `sender` value and marry them together ... simple 

Comment: How do  capture the indexpath of the selected row?@MadProgrammer

Comment: In the `didSelectRowAt` func, you're passed a `IndexPath` which contains the `section` and `row` which was selected

Comment: tempIndex = indexPath :- something like this, where tempIndex is just a variable ? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Well it depends, which is the problem with your question. Are you interested in the row and section? Are you interested in the data?  Is the user capable of selecting more the one item? Will you navigate to the new view when you detect a change in selection or is there a  seperate action the user needs to go through.  But, "yes" at a high level, you could do that

Comment: So all I'm interested in doing is capturing the data in the selected cell such as 'marketing', or 'legal' etc. and getting the same data as a textlabel in cell2 of my "Newcontroller" @MadProgrammer. I'd really appreciate some more help, you're much more experienced

Comment: The you need to capture the data, `selectedItem = typeExpertise[indexPath.row]` (where `selectedItem` is instance variable).  Once you have that you can pass it to the next controller, how you do that will depend on how you're building the navigation system, but, at the end of the day, you next controller will need to have a variable to receive the selected value

Comment: Apparently I declared the originalcontroller in the viewcontroller and now am trying to access the selectedItem and return the text in the cell, but it shows nothing @MadProgrammer